# Textbox value Change based on radiobutton selection laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I have one form i need to update the textbox value based on YES or NO radio button.If YES then it works fine but If NO then value of text box needs to be change. I am not able to update properly. I need to change the value of form text min_Delivery_Cost so i can update in db.

Here is my code..

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px" id="min_delivery_div">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Min. Delivery Cost</label>
    {{ Form::text('min_delivery_cost', null, array('placeholder' => 'Min. Delivery Cost', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

Here it radiobutton

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Home Delivery</label>
    <div class="radio">
        {{ Form::radio('home_delivery', '1', (Input::old('home_delivery') == '1'), array('id'=>'homedelivery1', 'onclick' => 'checkHomeDeliveryType();')) }}
        <label for="homedelivery1">Yes</label>
        {{ Form::radio('home_delivery', '0', (Input::old('home_delivery') == '0'), array('id'=>'homedelivery2', 'onclick' => 'checkHomeDeliveryType();')) }}
        <label for="homedelivery2">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here it is a Javascript

```
if(!$('#homedelivery2').is(":checked") && !$('#homedelivery2').is(":checked")) {
    $('#homedelivery1').attr("checked", true);

    $('#min_delivery_cost_div').show();
}
@if (Form::text('min_delivery_cost') == '0')


    $('#min_delivery_cost_div').hide();
@endif

function checkHomeDeliveryType() {
    if($('#homedelivery1').is(":checked")) {        
        $('#min_delivery_div').show();          
    } else if($('#homedelivery2').is(":checked")) {

        $('#min_delivery_div').hide();          
        $('#min_delivery_cost').val('0.00'));
        $("#min_delivery_cost").removeAttr('readonly');
    }
}
```

Comment: Found a solution for that...

Comment: $('input[name=min_delivery_cost]').val('0.00');

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked> Male
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){

    var i = $(this);

    alert(i.val());

});
```

Further Explanation:

Just bind a change event to your radio inputs. If you want to preserve the value ("caching") then just add a hidden input and change the value of that input or just trigger other functions within the change function.

Comment: I don't think this function will work because i am at edit controller it is not contain type thing in laravel.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I thought you just want to trigger a function which will change a text box depending on the selected radio button?

Btw. this line is missing quotations for the selector: 
$(#min_delivery_cost).val('0.00'));

Comment: You still have typos in your code: $('#min_delivery_cost').val('0.00'));

Comment: Please check your code for typos and test it again if your issue is solved. I have tested your checkHomeDeliveryType() function and it works like expected. (Enables text input and changes val to 0.00.)

Comment: OK. but i need to send that value to the database. which is not happening

Comment: Your question was how to update the input field, which we have solved if your javascript code does work now. 

I don't know why your post data doesn't contain the value, is your "min_delivery_cost" input field within the form tags? If the value changes correctly then please submit the form and take a look into the $_POST data array if all data is there (it should).

Comment: Hello I found the solution for the Question I asked... Thanks a lot @Dennis Heiden